# Oracle nvl, nvl2 and nullif functions

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

can we apply nvl or nvl2 function with nullif in oracle 
please give me some example of it

i have this query that is working fine

```
SELECT fName, LENGTH(fName) "First Name",
       lName, LENGTH(lName) "Last Name",
       NULLIF(LENGTH(fName), LENGTH(lName)) Output
FROM employee;
```

but i want to apply nvl on it when it return null value whaen fName and lName have same character

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are asking for. My suggestion would be to provide a sample set of data that you would have in your table, and then a sample of what you want as your output for the sample input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I followed, what's wrong with:

```
SELECT NVL(fName,'-1'), LENGTH(fName) "First Name",
       NVL(lName,'-1), LENGTH(lName) "Last Name",
       NVL(LENGTH(fName), LENGTH(lName)) Output
FROM employee;
```

And what is wrong with your query? Though I don't understand why are you using `NULLIF` on `LENGTH(fname)` , its slower and it will have the same effect as `NULLIF(fname)`